# Put Control in someone's hands

Tags: idiomatic-language

Which of these sentences is correct and natural?

- The paper suggests putting the control in the user's hands.
- The paper suggests putting control in the user's hands.

Comment: It is corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put *the control* in the user's hands

suggests that the control is a particular instrument/device or similar that allows the user to send commands to a system, whether electric gates, a computer game or whatever.

To put *control* in the user's hands

suggests that wider command of/responsibility for a system/organisation (rather than a particular device) is given to the user. The president might decide to put control of the attack in the hands of a particular general.